# ORACLE SQL - Obtener suma de sueldos solamente si vendedores hicieron ventas

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito sumar los sueldos de los vendedores solamente si hicieron ventas en la tabla VENTA y agruparlos por el código de sucursal, tengo solo esto pero me sigue trayendo todos los sueldos.

```
SELECT suc.cod_sucursal, SUM(vend.sueldo)
    FROM sucursal suc 
    JOIN vendedor vend ON (suc.cod_sucursal = vend.cod_sucursal)
    JOIN venta ON (vend.rut = venta.rut_vendedor)
    WHERE vend.rut IN venta.rut_vendedor
    GROUP BY suc.cod_sucursal
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Si no aportas algo mas de informacion de tu base de datos es dificil seguir los joins porque no se de que estas hablando.

Comment: Estas uniendo por rutas, si dos vendedores tienen la misma ruta te van a salir los registros de ambos aunque uno no tenga ventas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba algo como:

```
SELECT suc.cod_sucursal, SUM(vend.sueldo)
FROM sucursal suc
JOIN vendedor vend ON suc.cod_sucursal = vend.cod_sucursal
WHERE vend.rut IN (SELECT venta.rut_vendedor FROM venta)
GROUP BY suc.cod_sucursal
```

De todas formas, si subes más información (como, al menos, la estructura de la base de datos), puede ser que se te pueda ayudar mejor.

Comment: Hola, ¡exactamente eso dio lo que buscaba! Muchas gracias.